# Processing the data into a desired format in javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am new to JavaScript and want to process the following array -

```
var a = [
 "John-100",
 "Mark-120",
 "John-50",
 "Mark-130"
]
```

into the following format -

```
a = {
    "John": [100, 50],
    "Mark": [120, 130]
}
```

But have been unable to do so. Any help will be very much appreciated.

*Edit -* Any other format ideas where the marks of a particular student can be grouped together are also welcome.

Comment: the use of `var` makes me wonder if you're bound to an older version of javascript.  Also Are you sure you want to reassign the new object to the same variable?  Could clarify these things?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to achieve what you described:

```js
var a=[
 "John-100",
 "Mark-120",
 "John-50",
 "Mark-130"
]

function convertToSpecialObject(input) {
  //setup the output as an empty object
  const output = {};
  
  // iterate through input array one element at a time
  input.forEach(e => {
    // split the current element by dividing it into part[0] before the dash
    // and part[1] after the dash sign
    const parts = e.split(/-/);
    
    // now check the output object if it already contains a key for the part before the dash
    if(!output[parts[0]]) { 
      // in this case, we don't have a key for it previously
      // so lets set it up as a key with an empty array
      output[parts[0]] = []; 
    }
    
    // we must have already created a key or there is a key in existence
    // so let's just push the part after the dash to the current key
    output[parts[0]].push(Number(parts[1]));
  });
  
  // work done
  return output;
}

const b = convertToSpecialObject(a);

console.log(b);
```

Comment: The numbers are strings...

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thanks. I fixed my code to reflect your notice

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using `reduce and split method`

```js
var a=[
 "John-100",
 "Mark-120",
 "John-50",
 "Mark-130"
]

const b = a.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const _split = val.split('-');
  const name = _split[0]
  if(acc && acc[name]) {
    acc[name].push(+_split[1])
  } else {
    acc[name] = [+_split[1]]
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(b)
```

Comment: The numbers are strings....

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested, string split, and array reduce - add in an array map and it's a single line of code

```js
let a=["John-100","Mark-120","John-50","Mark-130"];

a=a.map(v=>v.split('-')).reduce((r,[n,m])=>({...r,[n]:[...r[n]||[],+m]}),{});

console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

The only answer with the correct result ... an array of NUMBERS

Comment: spread the accumulator and avoid returning assignment `=>({ ...r , [n] : [...r[n] || [], +m] })`

Comment: yeah, OK - I always forget that step

Answer (score 1):

With Simple Approach

```
const input = [
  "John-100",
  "Mark-120",
  "John-50",
  "Mark-130"
];


const getCustomObject = (arr) => {

  const obj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    const split = arr[i].split('-'); //spliting with '-'

    if (obj[split[0]]) {
      //push to existing array
      obj[split[0]].push(split[1]);

    } else {
      obj[split[0]] = []; //initilize array if no member
      obj[split[0]].push(split[1]);
    }
  };

  return obj;
}

console.log(getCustomObject(input));
```

Now numbers are not numerical values, It can be achieved with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in a very simple way by just using a [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method along with the [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Live Demo **:**

```js
var a = [
  "John-100",
  "Mark-120",
  "John-50",
  "Mark-130"
];

const obj = {};

a.forEach(element => {
  if (!obj[element.split('-')[0]]) {
    obj[element.split('-')[0]] = [];
  }
  obj[element.split('-')[0]].push(element.split('-')[1])
});

console.log(obj);
```